# Recommendation for intro to geometric integrators?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, symplectic-geometry

**Explicit Request**

Looking for book or lecture note recommendations on numerical optimization that (ideally) have the following:

1. Emphasis on geometric and physical intuition
2. Emphasis on symplectic integrators
3. Many well-thought out figures
4. Relatively self-contained (some of my background below)
5. Pseudo-code

**Goals**

I don't have what's called a "use case", but one of my goals is to able to better-understand i) how to code a symplectic integrator and ii) some intuition as to what math may be useful to advance the recent paper by M. Jordan et al.'s [On Symplectic Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03653).

Background: pure mathematics (algebraic geometry) and some background in physics. Never studied Hamiltonian dynamics proper and don't know what a "geometric integrator" is beyond the lovely Wikipedia article on it. Also used some of the standard gradient descent methods such as Nesterov and Adam in practice (ML), but can't say I really know the "physics" behind these methods.

Thank you!

**Addenda**

I haven't checked out the books by Hairer et al or Leimkuhler -- would one (or both?) fit the bill? It would be very useful to get comments on these books.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Hairer et al.'s [Geometric Numerical Integration](https://books.google.com/books?id=T1TaNRLmZv8C)?

Comment: Only the amazon.com entry and the three customer reviews therein. I wasn't able to find an electronic copy and didn't want to shell out $90 USD immediately. Does that book fit the five points above?

Comment: I second the recommendation for Hairer et al. I think the book satisfies all your requirements except point 5, but given your background I don't think that will be too much of a problem.

Comment: thanks for the Hairer et al recommendation. Please feel free to post as answer. How does this book compare with Leimkuhler, especially wrt the (tall order) of the five points?

Comment: You also might want to take a look at [McLachlan-Quispel survey](https://www.massey.ac.nz/~rmclachl/JPAReview.pdf) and [their lectures](http://www.mat.uc.pt/~alma/aulas/modelos/ficheiros/talks.pdf).

Comment: Another resource that may be of interest with regards to the symplectic integration side of things is this scicomp.stackexchange post:  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/what-does-symplectic-mean-in-reference-to-numerical-integrators-and-does-scip